# Using python-barcode trying to generate barcode and got error message: AttributeError: 'function' object has no attribute 'get'

Tags: python, python-3.x, function, barcode

I'm trying to do a simple function that will return .PNG file with barcode and nubmer at it's bottom.  I readed documentation (https://python-barcode.readthedocs.io/en/stable/barcode.html#creating-barcodes-as-image) and got no informations how to solve my error.

Here's a code:

```
def barcode():
    number = '123456789102'
    ean = barcode.get('ean13', number, writer = ImageWriter)
    PNG = ean.save('ean13')
barcode()
```

And here's an error

```
   ean = barcode.get("ean13", number, writer = ImageWriter) 
AttributeError: 'function' object has no attribute 'get'
```

What am I doing wrong? Using same commands like those in documentations work perfectly fine in *shell* but not as a separate program.

Comment: `def barcode`... Has no attribute `get`. Don't name functions after your imports

Comment: Just to expand what @OneCricketeer wrote.  You have a module named `barcode` with an attribute named `get`, and also a function named `barcode`.  Inside the function, `barcode` refers to the function.  Either rename your function, or change your import to be something like `import barcode as bc`, and then call `bc.get()`.

Answer (score 0):

You have to rename your function to avoid the error:

```py
def _barcode():
    number = '123456789102'
    ean = barcode.get('ean13', number, writer = ImageWriter)

_barcode()
```

To save it to PNG, change your code as follows:

```py
def _barcode():
    number = '123456789102'
    # ean = barcode.get('ean13', number, writer = ImageWriter)
    with open('test.png', 'wb') as f:
        _writer = ImageWriter()
        EAN13(number, _writer).write(f)

_barcode()
```